# Eclipse not picking oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, driver

I am getting oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver not found error when I run the java application. This driver is included in a jar the classpath. Still I am getting the same error. Can someone tell me how to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance.
Ganessin

Comment: Post the name of the jar you are using.

Comment: I am using classes12.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file `.classpath` which is located in the workspace directory of the project and see if the library is included. You may find something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/somelibrary.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: I have resolved this issue but now getting java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified